# C# razor - form request is getting a weird value for just one of the inputs entered

Tags: c#, razor

I have a form of give or take 30 inputs, many of them duplicates all functioning perfectly save for one value coming up as 'value',0 where 'value' was what was entered into the input and ',0' appears to have been appended by razor.

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="TOPS" id="11" /><!--input in question-->

<!--razor code im using to view the output-->
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys){
    <div>In Form: @(key): @Request.Form[key]</div><br/>
    int x;
    if(int.TryParse(Request.Form[key],out x) && x > -1){ 
        @:<div>Non numeric character (@Request.Form[key]) found</div>
    }
}
```

The key for the one input where key='TOPS' is giving the strange value. The others are all as expected.

Im very knew to csharp so apologies for any obvious mistakes but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You appear to have specified the value as 0 in the markup. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: For all the other inputs, which are exactly the same except having different names, the values are shown as I would expect but for this one particular input the value server side is coming up as 0,0. Im just puzzled as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have two inputs with the same name value: "TOPS". What you are seeing is a comma-separated string which represents both input values. That is how they are received by the server.